# SSL certificate not working on rails local after upgrading to Chrome 73

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, ssl, localhost

SSL certificate not working in rails local after upgrading chrome to chrome 73. It was working fine till chrome 70 and the latest version of safari. Using this link to set up the ssl cert on local https://gist.github.com/jed/6147872

Rails 5.2.2.1
Ruby 2.6.1

The error coming on chrome 73 is:

```
2019-04-22 13:34:07 +0530: SSL error, peer: 127.0.0.1, peer cert: , #<Puma::MiniSSL::SSLError: OpenSSL error: error:141F7065:SSL routines:final_key_share:no suitable key share - 337604709>
```

Comment: Please provide more details and logs if possible

Comment: Certificates work on general with Chrome 73. Certificates work on general with Rails. This means there is something special with your setup but from the few details provided it is not clear what - which makes the question too broad. I recommend that you a) check again if it works with different versions of Chrome and also other browsers and b) check with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and make sure that the server configuration gives you at least in A, because everything else might point to a configuration problem in your server.

Comment: updated with logs @DeepakMahakale

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error with Rails 5.2.3 and ruby 2.6.3p62, puma 3.12.4. I was trying to use a self-signed SSL certificate in my development environment, as instructed in [this link](https://github.com/codica2/rails-puma-ssl). I generated the key and cert with:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt
```

and then launched the server (puma in my case) with:

```
rails s -b 'ssl://localhost:3000?key=localhost.key&cert=localhost.crt'
```

but I was getting this error:

```
SSL error, peer: 172.23.0.1, peer cert: , #<Puma::MiniSSL::SSLError: OpenSSL error: error:141F7065:SSL routines:final_key_share:no suitable key share - 337604709>
```

I found a workaround in [this puma issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1670#issuecomment-439138076). I uninstalled the current puma gem:

```
gem uninstall puma
```

and replaced in my gemfile:

```
gem 'puma', '~> 4.3' #'~> 3.11'
#gem 'puma', git: 'https://github.com/eric-norcross/puma.git', branch: 'chrome_70_ssl_curve_compatiblity'
```

finally

```
bundle install
```

and it started to work. The commented puma gem from github also worked but gave me problems with websockets over ssl.

Comment: After testing many methods, finally it works! Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably have to do `bundle update puma` instead of `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

In this case try using below gem just instead of Pumagem

```
'puma', git: 'https://github.com/eric-norcross/puma.git', branch: 'chrome_70_ssl_curve_compatiblity'
```

this solve issue my end can